# CMD ipscanner explanation?

Tags: cmd, ip, ping

```
C:\>FOR /L %x in (1,1,255) do ping -n 1 192.168.1.%x | find /I "reply"
```

This command sends ping requests to all ip addresses from 192.168.1.%x ranging between (0 , 255)

Q: explanation of every word in the command.

Comment: see `for /?`, `ping /?` and `find /?`. Also there are some errors in your command:  a) Searching for `reply` is not reliable. Use `TTL` instead. b) it's comma or space, not dot in `(1.1.255)`c) Pipe symbol is `|`, not `/`. Resulting: `FOR /L %x in (1,1,255) do ping -n 1 192.168.1.%x |find "TTL"`

Comment: @Stephan, I'd be willing to say that even TTL won't work reliably in every language.

Comment: @Joey it seems, it's common sense, that "TTL" works. Do you have an example where it's not?

Comment: I don't, but I'm generally wary to check for text being present in command output that *may* be localised (also common sense, by the way). “Reply” surely is, but “TTL” still might. Don't have the patience of testing all Windows languages now, though. In any case, for one-off scripts that are not designed to be reliable or run in different environments such a choice is a moot point anyway. For reliable ones I just generally don't do that and probably would just take the third line of output.

Comment: Circumvent the localization issue by using the exit value: `FOR /L %x in (1,1,254) do @ping -n 1 -w 200 %x >nul || echo %x not alive`. This suppresses all text output of the `ping` command. The ping options make it ping once only (-n 1) and only wait for 200 msec (-w 200). Do not ping the broadcast address .255!

Comment: @user1016274 sorry, for a notexistent ip in my home network, `ping` says `Reply from <MyOwnIp>: Destination host unreachable.` and `Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss)`. `%errorlevel%` consequently is zero (no lost packages). So sadly this is also not reliable.

Comment: The `-w` option shortcuts this - if ping does not return within this short period it fails, with an Errorlevel of 1. Without, I get the same false positive as you.

Comment: @user1016274 looks as if you were right. Interesting. I'm going to test that extensively..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command does nothing, but I'm going to assume you actually meant the following:

```
FOR /L %x in (1,1,255) do ping -n 1 192.168.1.%x | find /I "reply"
```

Let's dissect it one by one:

1. `for` is a command that can do looping in various ways
2. `/L` means we're interested in a *counted* loop, e.g. like the `for` command in many programming languages.
3. `%x` is the loop variable. Loop variables in batch files are different from environment variables and thus have a different syntax as well.
4. `in` is just a piece of syntax that *always* goes with `for`. It is followed by a parenthesized expression that further clarifies what is looped over.
5. `(1,1,255)` are the loop boundaries. Start at `1`, increment by `1` each iteration and stop with `255`.
6. `do` is just another piece of syntax that always is present in `for` loops. It is followed by the command to execute each iteration.
7. `ping` is a command that sends ICMP PING packets to other hosts to see whether they respond.
8. `-n 1` is for pinging each host only once.
9. `192.168.1.%x` is the IP address of the host to ping. The last octet is replaced by the loop variable, which, as we remember, goes from `1` to `255`.
10. `|` is the vertical bar character, or, from pipelines in shells, often called “pipe” (even though I'd say, J looks more like a pipe, usually). This is used to pass output of the command on the left as input to the command on the right.
11. In this case the command on the right is `find`, which is an ancient, archaic program to search for text in files and program output and returns those lines. (Seriously: Use `findstr` nowadays, unless you're counting lines.
12. `/I` means that we search case-insensitively.
13. `"reply"` is the word we search for.

Putting it all together, this is a line that pings every IP address (even the broadcast address) in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet and prints only the replies. In PowerShell terms we can achieve the same with

```
Test-Connection (1..255|%{"192.168.1.$_"}) -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

(which is approximately just one call to `ping` with lots of addresses that are actually pinged in parallel).